# deploying angular 9 with django drf with docker - requests gets rejected

Tags: django, angular, docker, nginx, django-rest-framework

#### Disclaimer: sorry for my bad english and I am new to angular, django and production.

I am trying to push the first draft of what I've made into a local production server I own running CentOS 7.
Up until now i was working in dev mode with `proxy.config.json` to bind between the Django and Angular so far so good.

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "example.me",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

when I wanted to push to production however i failed to bind the container frontend with backend. these are the setup i made

1. Containerizing angular and putting the compiled files in an NGINX container -- port 3108
2. Containerizing Django and running gunicorn -- port 80
3. Postgres image

### DockerFiles and Docker-compose

#### Django Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

# USER app
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

#### Angular Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.16.2 AS build
LABEL version="0.0.1"
WORKDIR /app
COPY ["package.json","npm-shrinkwrap.json*","./"]
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN npm install --silent
COPY . .
RUN ng build --prod

FROM nginx:latest
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /app/dist/frontend /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE "3108"
```

#### Docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=database_name
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    networks:
      - app
  backend:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:80 myproject.wsgi
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - app
    depends_on: 
      - db
  frontend:
    build: 
      context: ../frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: nginx -g "daemon off;"
    ports:
      - "3108:3108"
    networks:
      - app
    depends_on:
      - backend

networks:
  app:
```

#### NGINX config file

```
server {
  listen 3108;
  server_name example.me;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;

  }
}
```

I tried to mimic the the angular proxy by adding 
following one answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598339/how-to-deploy-angular-8-ssr-and-django-rest-framework-separately-on-the-same-ser) when he talked about docker

```
 location /api {
    proxy_pass example.me;
    }
```

this resulted of the backend return `Error 403`

then I changed the BaseEndPoint to request directly from the server and added `corsheaders` to django and started getting a `401 Error`.

#### environment.prod

```
export const environment = {
      production: true,
      ConfigApi: {
            BaseEndPoint: 'example.me',
            LoginEndPoint: '/api/account/login/',
        RegisterEndPoint: '/api/account/registration/',
        MembersList: '/api/membres_list/',
        Meeting: '/api/meeting/create_list/',
        TaskList: '/api/task_list/create/',
        }
    };
```

I can't point out the issue or its source; i should point out that request from Postman to the backend works just fine.

#### TL;DR

Backend keeps rejecting Frontend requests with `403` or `401` and i don't know why

Comment: This sounds like a problem of the headers of the requests

Comment: You have to add CORS allowed hosts to the Django settings.