# How to deploy angular( frontend ) and django ( backend ) in GoDaddy or heroku

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework, web-deployment

I have done a basic project with angular and django. For django alone I have used pythonanywhere.com to deploy my project.
How to deploy the django rest framework and angular?

Comment: There's nothing particularly special about this setup. Angular code is just static files, and can be served from whatever point you want; then the api calls to the REST backend go to the endpoint you determined.

But to have an idea, you can have a look at this answer of a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57609549/4329342

Comment: There is nothing that prevents you from running drf & angular on PythonAnywhere.